# golang gin gonic content-type not setting to application/json with c.JSON

Tags: json, go

According to the [official documentation](https://gowalker.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context_JSON), c.JSON of [gin-gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) should set the response header to `application/json`, but when I call my API from [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), the response header is set to `text/plain; charset=utf-8`

I don't understand what I am missing, any idea ?

Doc :

> **func JSON**
>
> JSON serializes the given struct as JSON into the response body. It
>   also sets the Content-Type as "application/json".

Here is a sample of my code :

```
func postLogin(c *gin.Context) {
    var credentials DTO.Credentials
    if err := c.BindJSON(&credentials); err == nil {
        c.JSON(buildResponse(services.CheckUserCredentials(credentials)))
    } else {
        var apiErrors = DTO.ApiErrors{}
        for _, v := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
            apiErrors.Errors = append(apiErrors.Errors, DTO.ApiError{Field: v.Field, Message: v.Field + " is " + v.Tag})
        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, apiErrors)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

After investigation, log.Println(c.Writer.Header().Get("Content-Type")) doesn't print any thing, showing content-type is empty as it should be.

```
func writeContentType(w http.ResponseWriter, value []string) {
    header := w.Header()
    log.Println(header.Get("Content-Type")) // <=========== Nothing happen
    if val := header["Content-Type"]; len(val) == 0 {
        header["Content-Type"] = value
    }
}
```

I really don't want to have to add `c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")` to every route in my architecture...

**EDIT 2**

It seems like `binding:"required"` break the Content-Type Header

```
type Credentials struct {
    Email         string        `json:"email" binding:"required"`
    Password      string        `json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the source, it looks like it won't write the `Content-Type` header if it is already set.

`c.JSON` calls [this function](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@e2212d40c62a98b388a5eb48ecbdcf88534688ba/-/blob/render/json.go#L39) which calls the following code:

```
func writeContentType(w http.ResponseWriter, value []string) {
    header := w.Header()
    if val := header["Content-Type"]; len(val) == 0 {
        header["Content-Type"] = value
    }
}
```

Therefore your `Content-Type` must be set somewhere else.

Comment: Nice catch ! So anyway I could make it "unset" so it set it automatically as wanted?

Comment: First I would verify that your header is set. But you could set the headers to `nil` as such: `w.Header() = nil`. This seems silly to have to do, but I suppose that is the API's choice.

Comment: c.Writer.Header().Write(nil) don't change the result and yes it is silly :(

Comment: Ah I wrote the wrong thing. You need to delete the `Content-Type` header. You can do this: `w.Header().Del("Content-Type")`.

Comment: Yeah I tried, not working, the only way is to write  c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json") but that is supper ugly do add that everywhere, I am frustrated ^^

Comment: HEY, wait a minute, this function do absolutely nothing, header is a function variable and go nowhere after ... @squiguy

Comment: What do you mean "function variable" and that it goes nowhere after?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130442/discussion-between-adrien-and-squiguy).

Answer (score 11):

Use `c.ShouldBindJSON(&credentials)` instead of `c.BindJSON`.

> [Gin README.md - Model binding and validation](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation)
>
> These methods use MustBindWith under the hood. If there is a binding
> error, the request is aborted with c.AbortWithError(400,
> err).SetType(ErrorTypeBind). This sets the response status code to 400
> and the Content-Type header is set to text/plain; charset=utf-8.

As [Eutychus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4928027/eutychus) said in a comment: `c.BindJSON` uses `MustBindWith` under the hood. If there is a binding error, the request is aborted and the response status code is set to 400 and the `Content-Type` header is set to `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

The `ShouldBindJSON` uses `ShouldBindWith` under the hood. If there is a binding error, the error is returned and it is the developer's responsibility to handle the request and error appropriately. That is why it is the better one in this case.

Answer (score 8):

If you expect all your requests to be JSON, add a middle ware instead.

```
func JSONMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

On your router add

```
router.Use(JSONMiddleware())
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your output is not actually valid JSON and fails marshal. I saw content-type being set to application/text when i was not returning in an error handler, and i was accidentally concatenating a string onto JSON as a result of my poor error handling.