# Change Content-Type header in Gin middleware

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a custom gin middleware set up to handle errors but however, it does change to the `Content-Type` header.

```
package middleware

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

func validationErrorToText(e validator.FieldError) string {
    switch e.Tag() {
    case "required":
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s is required", e.Field())
    case "max":
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s cannot be longer than %s", e.Field(), e.Param())
    case "min":
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s must be longer than %s", e.Field(), e.Param())
    case "email":
        return fmt.Sprintf("Invalid email format")
    case "len":
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s must be %s characters long", e.Field(), e.Param())
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s is not valid", e.Field())
}

func Errors() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()
        // Only run if there are some errors to handle
        if len(c.Errors) > 0 {
            for _, e := range c.Errors {
                // Find out what type of error it is
                switch e.Type {
                case gin.ErrorTypePublic:
                    // Only output public errors if nothing has been written yet
                    if !c.Writer.Written() {
                        c.JSON(c.Writer.Status(), gin.H{"error": e.Error()})
                    }
                case gin.ErrorTypeBind:
                    errs := e.Err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
                    list := make(map[int]string)

                    for field, err := range errs {
                        list[field] = validationErrorToText(err)
                    }
                    // Make sure we maintain the preset response status
                    status := http.StatusBadRequest
                    if c.Writer.Status() != http.StatusOK {
                        status = c.Writer.Status()
                    }
                    c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    c.JSON(status, gin.H{
                        "status": "error",
                        "errors": list,
                    })

                default:
                    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"errors": c.Errors.JSON()})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a `text/plain; charset=utf-8` in the response `Content-Type` header instead.

Comment: The application does not set the content type in the gin.ErrorTypePublic  branch of the type switch.

Comment: @thwd I am testing for the `gin.ErrorTypeBind` case, where I'm explicitly set the `Content-Type` header

Comment: Should you have a response for the case where e.Type == gin.ErrorTypePublic and c.Writer.Written is true?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109065/golang-gin-gonic-content-type-not-setting-to-application-json-with-c-json

Comment: @ChidiWilliams TBH, I'm not sure

Comment: @MrFoh the c.Next()'s position. you are leaving the function without running the content. Change that first and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that calling methods like `c.AbortWithStatus` (or `c.BindJSON`) leads to actually writing headers, since under the hood they invoke `c.Writer.WriteHeaderNow()`. You cannot overwrite the header afterwards.

The solution is pretty simple:

- do not use `c.BindJSON`, call `c.ShouldBindJSON` and then handle binding errors manually
- do not use `c.AbortWithError`, call `c.Status(http.StatusBadRequest)`, `c.Error(err)`, `c.Abort()` (in any order)

You can create a wrapper just for that:

```golang
func BindJSON(c *gin.Context, obj interface{}) error {
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(obj); err != nil {
        c.Status(http.StatusBadRequest)
        c.Error(err)
        c.Abort()
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code `c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")` as the 1st line in the function body `func(c *gin.Context) {...}`

The problem is this package gin changes the header somewhere internally even before you call the c.JSON function. That's the issue.